# How to install HTML::Entities in perl

Tags: perl

When I enter

```
cpan[1]> install HTML::Entities
```

in perl, I get

```
All tests successful.
Files=48, Tests=451,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.21 usr  0.10 sys +  1.54 cusr  0.26 csys =  2.11 CPU)
Result: PASS
  GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.72.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level/HTML'
mkdir /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl: Permission denied at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 494.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1.
make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 13
  GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.72.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 PETDANCE/HTML-Tagset-3.20.tar.gz             : install NO
 GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.72.tar.gz                 : install NO
```

Possibly the problem lies with perl trying to install to a directory called 5.16.3; my version of perl is 5.22.1. I am using a mac and the homebrew package manager. Why can't I `make install` modules in perl?

Comment: in the directory `/opt/local/lib/perl5` there are two versions of perl, 5.16.3 and 5.22.

Comment: are both verisons owned by the same user?

Comment: Yes, both versions are owned by the same user.

Comment: is that user tha same as the suer you are running cpan as? what are the permissions on `/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3`

Comment: Your user does not have permission to the directory. Use Local::Lib.

Comment: Try running cpan as root?

Comment: if you need an alternative perl it might be better to use perlbrew for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows that the user have no authority to create files; Please run cpan with root or with --prefix